# Emacs : file "hilit19" missing and display problems

Tags: emacs

I've downloaded an already complete .emacs file in order to program in c ++ comfortably.

I have problems with quotation marks "..." that are displayed in two different colors. I think this problem may be linked with this : (thanks to "emacs --debug-init")

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type" "hilit19")


require(hilit19)
```

How can I get hilit19 or say to emacs to use it ?

Comment: Googling for `hilit.el` shows several locations you can try to get it from. Then put it in your `load-path`. And maybe `M-x byte-compile-file` it.

Comment: The reason it's called `hilit19` is that it was current when you had Emacs 19, which would presubably be almost 20 years ago. You should definitely be very skeptical of anything which requires it today.

Answer (score 1):

Hilit19 was added to Emacs in 1994, moved to `lisp/obsolete/` in 2001, and finally removed from Emacs in 2008.

Note that when it appeared in Emacs-19.18 it was already obsolete, since font-lock was added in the previous released (Emacs-19.17) and font-lock is like hilit19 but fancier since it worked "on the fly" (hilit19 only updated the highlighting after an explicit keypress).

So, like triplee said:

> You should definitely be very skeptical of anything which requires it today.